# Validation Expressions

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I need to validate textbox value.
The value for validation expression for following two conditions:

- first part of string, only four letters
- the next part of string, only six numbers,
- the next part of string, only 0 or 2 or 3 letters or numbers.

I use the next validation expressions for the first and second validations:

```
ValidationExpression="[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{6}"
```

but for the last validation try the next expression validation:

```
ValidationExpression="[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{6}[0-9 A-Z]{0-3}"
```

But not working. Can anyone help?

Comment: `but not working`. Famous last words.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? And did you intend to have a space in the last part of that expression? That is, you have `[0-9 A-Z]`. Did you mean `[0-9A-Z]`? Finally, I think your primary problem is that `{0-3}` should be `{0,3}`. You said, "only 0 or 2 or 3 leters or numbers." So 1 letter/number isn't valid?

Answer (score 1):

```
ValidationExpression="[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{6}([0-9A-Z]{2,3})?"
```

Comment: For some reason, he said the final expression was length 0, 2, or 3 not 0-3

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned "letters" but in your code you have assumed all uppercase (capital) letters instead. If you want to accept capital letters only for the letter parts, then simonweijgers's answer is correct.

However, to allow lowercase letters as well:

```
ValidationExpression="[A-Za-z]{4}[0-9]{6}([0-9A-Za-z]{2,3})?"
```

And to explain a bit: The `?` allows the expression in the parentheses to validate zero or one time, meaning that it either has 2 or 3 or it doesn't have any at all (0 letters/numbers).